# iOS9 Quick Reply from lock screen API

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios9

Is it possible to add functionality for "quick reply" from lock screen like imessage? Ive searched and can only find rumors that it exists but nothing in the docs.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could explain more clearly what you mean by a "quick reply."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)Yes, it can be possible. It is named as **Interactive notification**. It is introduced in iOS 8.

2)  Here is the [blog](http://www.imore.com/interactive-notifications-ios-8-explained) explaining the interactive notification

3)Also there is [tutorial](https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/) 
present on web for integrating in the App